# DynamicReports Eliminates Time Portion Of Date Fields

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using [dynamic-reports](http://dynamicreports.org) to create reports based on Jasper-reports.

I have encountered this odd problem that When I am creating reports that contains columns with Timestamp values, the time portion of those values got eliminated and values of those columns in the report are shown without their time portion, For example, I expect `2013-03-12 23:10:10.2` but get `2013-03-12 0:0:0.0`.

I am using `DataTypes.dateYearToSecondType()` type of dynamicreports data types.

I am currently using jasperreports-5.5.1 and dynamicreports-3.2.1

Any help will be apreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the trick is to use this column definition instead  :

> TextColumnBuilder column = col.column(...,
>   Timestamp.class).setPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.sss");

as ricardo mariaca answered [here](http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=893&sid=1a297dee3cb5b2bb630a2a38647ec72b)